# How to use pow() in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, pow, exponent

I have this solution, in nineteen languages. I needs a pow() function (or operator) to calc from increase to interest rate and from interest rate to increase. The only language I can't calc it is in Objective-C. How to use it?

This works:

```
NSLog(@"Pow = %f", pow(1.03, 0.5));
```

This don't works:

```
- (double) pot: (double) value exponent: (double) e {
    return pow(value, e);
}
```

It gives this error:

```
/usr/sbin/ld: /tmp/ccYQw9Wv.ltrans0.ltrans.o: undefined reference to symbol 'pow@@GLIBC_2.29'
/usr/sbin/ld: /usr/lib/libm.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: @esqew This is a linker error, so compilation already succeeded. I suspect he hasn't linked against glibc, although I thought that would be done by default.

Comment: Maybe this is because I am using jdoodle on-line compiler.